# child_process stream backpressure

Tags: node.js, stream, stdio

I'm using [`exec-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-stream) with Node.js and piping that stream through a few other transform streams, eventually through a [`node-brake`](https://github.com/substack/node-brake) stream to limit the data rate.  The braking stream seems to have no effect, and in fact data eventually is lost at the end of a long chain.

```
execStream('some-external-binary').pipe(transform1).pipe(transform2).pipe(brake(1024))
```

What I think is happening is that the `child_process` `STDOUT` stream (within `exec-stream`) is not pausing, and therefore buffers fill until data is lost.

Do `child_process` streams behave this way?  Is there any way to get backpressure to work properly with `child_process` streams?

Comment: I don't have that much experience with exec-stream or node-brake, but I wanted to explore your issue with a full example.  Does https://gist.github.com/CodeLenny/007523ae5b13559e644f29b46364c1e4 match the behavior you experienced?  It looks to me like the brake does not back-pressure, but I'm not getting different amounts of data cut off when using different brake values.

Comment: @RyanLeonard Interesting.  Perhaps the issue here all along is that `node-brake` doesn't do what I expected.  Yes, that seems to be a good emulation of the problem.  Could you please post that as an answer?

Comment: I've written the comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with exec-stream and node-brake to understand all the avenues for data-loss.

However, I did a little experiment to see if node-brake has a back-pressure effect, which you mentioned could be a potential area for data-loss.

File is also hosted on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/CodeLenny/007523ae5b13559e644f29b46364c1e4).

```
###
Created for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982953/child-process-stream-backpressure
Please pardon the CoffeeScript, but I couldn't stand to extend stream.Transform in native JavaScript.
###
fs = require("fs")
execStream = require("exec-stream")
brake = require("brake")

file = fs.createWriteStream("tmp.txt")

class Double extends require("stream").Transform
  _transform: (chunk, enc, cb) ->
    @_last ?= Date.now()
    @_called ?= []
    @_called.push Date.now() - @_last
    @_last = Date.now()
    @push chunk.toString() + chunk.toString()
    cb()

class UpperCase extends require("stream").Transform
  _transform: (chunk, enc, cb) ->
    @push chunk.toString().toUpperCase()
    cb()

sum = (nums) ->
  o = 0
  o += i for i in nums
  o

doTest = (size) ->

  transform1 = new Double()
  transform2 = new UpperCase()
  transform3 = new Double()

  execStream("dd", ["if=/dev/urandom", "bs=1024", "count=1"])
    .pipe(transform1)
    .pipe(transform2)
    .pipe(brake(size))
    .pipe(transform3)
    .pipe(file)

  file.on "finish", ->
    fs.stat "tmp.txt", (err, stats) ->
      throw err if err
      called1 = transform1._called
      averagePreBrake = sum(called1) / called1.length
      called2 = transform3._called
      averagePostBrake = sum(called2) / called2.length
      console.log """
        Generated with brake(#{size}): #{stats.size}
        Average time between transformations pre-brake:  #{averagePreBrake}ms
        Average time between transformations post-brake: #{averagePostBrake}ms
      """

doTest 1024
doTest 256
```

Results of the process are below.

[image: stdout from above Coffeescript]

I notice that there are no gaps between transformations before the brake.  However, the brake disrupts transformations later down the line.  Given this data, I suspect that node-brake has no back-pressure effect.

[Screenshot of console output generated by my [sh2png](https://github.com/CodeLenny/sh2png) utility]